# how can i import Document in python module docx?

Tags: python, python-2.x, docx, python-docx

I'm using mac and installing python-docx using pip. I went into C:\Python27\Scripts and ran

```
pip install python-docx
```

I thought it should have been installed.

But when i run a simple import

```
from docx import Documents
```

it ran into an

```
ImportError: No module named docx
```

when i checked the modules installed using pip using `pip list` python-docx 0.8.11 is installed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The same `python` you use to install python-docx should be the same `python` you use to run your app/script: `python -m pip install python-docx`. Or better, use a virtual environment, then install and run from inside the venv.

Answer (score 1):

please try to install the `python-docx` :

```
$ pip uninstall docx
$ pip install python-docx
```

Comment: For Anaconda:
`conda install -c conda-forge python-docx`, see also https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-docx